# Restrict Users permission to access data in ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

Is it possible to allow only specific users from databricks to access specific data from Azure Data Lake Storage?

I want to allow only User 1 and User 2 to access data1.csv file and allow User 3 and User 4 to access data2.csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **Premium** feature in Azure Databricks that allows to authenticate to Azure Data Lake Store using the Azure Active Directory identity logged into Azure Databricks. With this feature customers can control which user can access which data through Azure Databricks.

This feature needs to be enabled on the cluster (see screenshot below) and once configured, users can then log-in & execute read/write commands to Azure Data Lake Store without the need to use service principle. The user can only read/write data based on the roles and ACLs the user has been granted on the Azure Data Lake Store.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough#--enable-azure-data-lake-storage-credential-passthrough-for-a-standard-cluster